# How to use Stacking Order of Multiple Backgrounds with jQuery .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

How can I target multiple background property with css() in jQuery

Example:

```
    body {    
       background: 
          url("img1.png"),
          url("img2.png"),
          url("img3.png");
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the css method like you would any other style attribute.

```
$('body').css('background-image', 
   'url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_flwr.gif"),'
   + 'url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/paper.gif")'
);
```